# Show images - Screen is stuck

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a WPF application.
The application receives bitmap images and display them.
The application receives the images from a camera and it should display them near real time.
The screen is getting stuck.
The result should be a video.

How can I fix it?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the bitmaps on a background thread and then `Freeze()` them before consuming them on the UI thread.

Comment: I am receiving the images from a camera it should be near real time

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't load images in main thread. Try some async library/pattern for loading images like [this](http://dotnetlearning.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/loading-images-asynchronously-in-wpf/) one. Worked for me.